# Is there a simple html-webserver for mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, mamp

Sometimes when I do front-end development, I use **MAMP** as a web-server so that I don't have to deal with **CORS**-errors. Since I upgraded to mavericks MAMP won't work any more and it is pretty heavy. Is there something simpler or more lightweight built in or easily installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on how simple you like it:

Python 2:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Python 3:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.server.html

Comment: If anyone is intersted I wrote a short tutorial below.

Comment: FYI while I use this all the time, it's only good for static files, HTML, CSS, JS, etc. It doesn't handle PHP files, or any other dynamic language.

Answer (score 3):

[http-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server)

Install:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

Start:

```
http-server -p port -a address
```

Comment: How is having to install npm simpler than using something that comes with OS X by default, such as Python?

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is a well-known local webserver. I'm told it works quite similar to MAMP

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the folder you want to open and write:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

8000 is the port, you may change it.

The terminal will respond with something like Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...

if you navigate to the adress 0.0.0.0:8000 you will see your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

`php -S localhost:3000`

Or the port you want.